# When I left swipe sliding tabs the left navigation drawer opens up

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs, navigation, navigation-drawer

I'm using material design sliding tabs(smartTabLayout), here: https://github.com/ogaclejapan/SmartTabLayout

And, material design side navigation drawer(android reside menu), here : https://github.com/SpecialCyCi/AndroidResideMenu

The problem I'm facing is: When I swipe left from any of the tabs, the navigation drawer opens up, but it is fine when I swipe right.

[image: Tab on the extreme right]

[image: This is what happens when I swipe left. The drawer opens up]

Here is the code:

MainActivity.java :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    private SectionsPageAdapter sectionsPageAdapter;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    Toolbar toolbar;
    ResideMenu resideMenu;
    SmartTabLayout smartTabLayout;
    private MainActivity mContext;
    private ResideMenuItem equalizer;
    private ResideMenuItem ringtonemaker;
    private ResideMenuItem identifysong;
    private ResideMenuItem themes;
    private ResideMenuItem rateus;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mContext = MainActivity.this;
        setUpMenu();


        toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        sectionsPageAdapter = new SectionsPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);

        smartTabLayout = (SmartTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.viewpagertab);
        smartTabLayout.setViewPager(viewPager);



    }


    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {

        SectionsPageAdapter adapter = new SectionsPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new Albums(), "Albums");
        adapter.addFragment(new Artists(), "Artists");
        adapter.addFragment(new Songs(), "Songs");
        adapter.addFragment(new Playlists(), "Playlists");
        adapter.addFragment(new Genres(), "Genres");
        adapter.addFragment(new My_Files(), "My Files");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        viewPager.setPageTransformer(true, new CubeInTransformer());

    }

        private void setUpMenu() {

        // attach to current activity;
        resideMenu = new ResideMenu(this);
        resideMenu.setBackground(R.drawable.city);
        resideMenu.attachToActivity(this);
        //valid scale factor is between 0.0f and 1.0f. leftmenu'width is 150dip.
        resideMenu.setScaleValue(0.6f);

        // create menu items;
        equalizer = new ResideMenuItem(this, R.drawable.city, "Equalizer");
        ringtonemaker = new ResideMenuItem(this, R.drawable.city, "Ringtone Maker");
        identifysong = new ResideMenuItem(this, R.drawable.city, "Identify Song");
        themes = new ResideMenuItem(this, R.drawable.city, "Theme");
        rateus = new ResideMenuItem(this, R.drawable.city, "Rate us");

        equalizer.setOnClickListener(this);
        ringtonemaker.setOnClickListener(this);
        identifysong.setOnClickListener(this);
        themes.setOnClickListener(this);
        rateus.setOnClickListener(this);

        resideMenu.addMenuItem(equalizer, ResideMenu.DIRECTION_LEFT);
        resideMenu.addMenuItem(ringtonemaker, ResideMenu.DIRECTION_LEFT);
        resideMenu.addMenuItem(identifysong, ResideMenu.DIRECTION_LEFT);
        resideMenu.addMenuItem(themes, ResideMenu.DIRECTION_LEFT);
        resideMenu.addMenuItem(rateus, ResideMenu.DIRECTION_LEFT);

        // You can disable a direction by setting ->
        resideMenu.setSwipeDirectionDisable(ResideMenu.DIRECTION_RIGHT);

    }



    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

    }
}
```

Adapter for sliding tabs:

```
class SectionsPageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private final List<Fragment> FragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> FragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String Title){

        FragmentList.add(fragment);
        FragmentTitleList.add(Title);
    }


    public SectionsPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return FragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
       return FragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return FragmentList.size();
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/city"

tools:context="com.musicplayer.musicana.MainActivity">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="30dp"
    android:title="Musicana"
    app:titleTextColor="#ffffff">

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

<com.ogaclejapan.smarttablayout.SmartTabLayout
    android:id="@+id/viewpagertab"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
    app:stl_indicatorAlwaysInCenter="false"
    app:stl_indicatorWithoutPadding="false"
    app:stl_indicatorInFront="false"
    app:stl_indicatorInterpolation="smart"
    app:stl_indicatorGravity="center"
    app:stl_indicatorColor="#40C4FF"
    app:stl_indicatorThickness="30dp"
    app:stl_indicatorWidth="110dp"
    app:stl_indicatorCornerRadius="10dp"
    app:stl_overlineColor="#4D000000"
    app:stl_overlineThickness="0dp"
    app:stl_underlineColor="#ffffff"
    app:stl_underlineThickness="0dp"
    app:stl_dividerColor="#ffffff"
    app:stl_dividerThickness="0dp"
    app:stl_defaultTabBackground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
    app:stl_defaultTabTextAllCaps="false"
    app:stl_defaultTabTextColor="#ffffff"
    app:stl_defaultTabTextSize="16sp"
    app:stl_defaultTabTextHorizontalPadding="30dp"
    app:stl_defaultTabTextMinWidth="0dp"
    app:stl_distributeEvenly="false"
    app:stl_clickable="true"
    app:stl_titleOffset="24dp"
    app:stl_drawDecorationAfterTab="false"
    />

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/viewpagertab"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: May be this is what you are looking for? `resideMenu.addIgnoredView(viewPager);`

Comment: No, I tried this. This just blocks the whole viewpager from accessing the side nav drawer. I want to open the side nav drawer when I swipe left the first tab. Anyways, appreciate your help :)

Comment: you could try something like, when you reach the first fragment on viewpager, then remove the ignoredView and when u are on other pages, add Viewpager to ignored view.

Comment: Yeah I'll try that. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I can see [here](https://github.com/SpecialCyCi/AndroidResideMenu/blob/master/ResideMenu/src/com/special/ResideMenu/ResideMenu.java) method `dispatchTouchEvent` don't have possibility to set drag area to avoid ViewPager touch interception. So, you can fork this repo and add that functionality. Or you can override activity's `dispatchTouchEvent`:

```
boolean menuDragging = false;  

public boolean isInsideMenuDragArea(MotionEvent ev) {
    return ev.getX() < 200; // THIS IS PIXELS, NOT DP!
}

@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    if (menuDragged) return resideMenu.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
    if (ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
         if (!isInsideMenuDragArea(ev)) {
              return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
         } else {
              menuDragging = true;
         }    
    } else if (ev.getAction() ==  MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
         menuDragging = false;
    }
    return resideMenu.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);

}
```

I think this is enough to understand what I mean

**EDIT:**

If you want to open the side nav drawer when you swipe left the first tab

```
viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {}
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {}

    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        if (position == 0) resideMenu.removeIgnoredView(viewPager);
        else resideMenu.addIgnoredView(viewPager);
    }
});
```

**EDIT2:**
Add this to your activity

```
boolean resideMenuEnabled = true;

public void setResideMenuEnabled(boolean enabled) {
     if (resideMenuEnabled != enabled) {
          if (enabled) resideMenu.removeIgnoredView(viewPager);
          else resideMenu.addIgnoredView(viewPager);
          resideMenuEnabled = enabled;
     }
}
```

And use it like this

```
viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {}
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {}

    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        if (position == 0) setResideMenuEnabled(true);
        else setResideMenuEnabled(false);
    }
});
```

Comment: I have overridden dispatchTouchEvent in my activity but still no luck :(

Comment: This seems to be working for the first two tabs. But when I got the rightmost tab and come back to the first tab and swipe left, nothing happens. Well, Thanks for your time :)

Comment: When I swipe till "artists" tab and come back it works fine, but when I swipe till "songs" tab and other tabs ahead and then come back, then the left swipe doesn't work. I even tried implementing gestures, but nothing helped. Please help me! :(

Comment: @SebinPaul EDIT2

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm! You are a pro! Can you tell me the logic behind it?

Comment: @SebinPaul method addIgnoredView was called many times in EDIT1. ResideMenu use array to collect ignored views. But removeIgnoredView was called only for first tab. So you ignore the same view many times, and unignore it only one time. To avoid that in EDIT2 we use boolean flag which guarantee that addIgnoredView can be called only after removeIgnoredView and removeIgnoredView also can be called only after addIgnoreView

Comment: I mean the difference between the code you gave earlier and this one.